# Keep LINQPad results for next query

Tags: c#, linqpad

Example query:

```
var booksFromPetr = Books.Where(x=> x.Author=="Petr Heteša");
```

Let's say this query takes too long to finish execution, but after it results in  10 books..

Now I want to work with these books, but don't want to wait for first query **again**...

Somehow I need to re-use `booksFromPeter` variable...

I am looking for something like matlab workspace...

Comment: I am having a really hard time understanding what you are asking.  Can you  edit your question to attempt to clarify a bit?

Comment: Without waiting for the query to finish hoe would you get 10 books?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya You don't want to wait over and over again as you attempt to develop further queries based on your initial results.

Comment: Are you saying that the query delivers 10 book after a long time but if you let it continue it might return more than 10?  Or are you saying that it only returns 10 book but it takes a long time to complete the query?  If it is the latter, you can materialize the query into a list by calling `var booksFromPetr = Books.Where(x=> x.Author=="Petr Heteša").ToList();`  Then  you can work with the list in memory.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The latter (question updated). Ok.. But - how to use `booksFromPetr` without re-initialization? How to access this in memory variable in another Linqpad Query?

Comment: When you call `ToList` the query is executed and the data is materialized into memory into a `List<Book>`.  You can then access those books repeatedly, through the `booksFromPetr` variable, without the query being resent to the server.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I understand what ToList is doing... But you didn't tell me HOW to access this in memory variable in another LinqPad execution...?

Comment: You could add .Cache() to the end to store the results in the AppDomain. The next time you run the values will be pulled from the cache instead of the query being re-run.

Answer (score 2):

LINQPad isn't really designed for interactive calculating - you would need to add additional calculations and re-run the entire query.

However, one thing you could do is use

```
booksFromPetr.Dump("Books From Petr", true);
```

to output the results into a grid and then you can copy the grid into a spreadsheet and save as CSV or paste it back into LINQPad as a variable definition.

You could alternatively add code to serialize the result objects to disk and then load them in another query.

Or save them in your database in a working table.

I sympathize as I have a recursive disk walk that takes 2.5 hours to run and the first time I ran it, I didn't realize converting to a grid re-runs the entire query (if you didn't put `.ToList()` on the end, or something similar), so when I used the View in grid menu option, I had to wait another 2.5 hours to copy the grid to a spreadsheet.

I've also worked on a model that uses CSV files over 270MB and take over a minute just to count the rows, so iterating on the queries to work out the final results can be painful. Fortunately the CSV driver caches the data so most of the time my iterations are quicker.

It would be nice if there was a way to continue on like it was a calculator, but hard to design and implement I think.